# Jquery replacewith fade/animate

Tags: jquery

I know there are loads of questions on replacewith but none seem to have answers that apply to my situation.

html: `<div id="foo"></div>`

I want #foo to be faded out, then I want to replace the whole thing (not just the contents) with essentially the same thing `<div id="foo"></div>` which is faded in.

Thanks

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
$('#foo').fadeOut("slow", function(){
    var div = $("<div id='foo'>test2</div>").hide();
    $(this).replaceWith(div);
    $('#foo').fadeIn("slow");
});
```

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/9Dubr/1/

Updated to fade in correctly

Comment: In case someone runs into the same issue: Note that `replaceWith()` removes the content before inserting the new content. For an unnoticable short period of time the free space is filled by other elements in the flow. If one of those elements actually triggers the fade on `mouseenter`, that element is moved away from the cursor and then back "under" it causing the event to trigger periodically. To fix this, wrap the faded element in a div with a fixed height (at least while fading). This actually took me a couple of hours to figure out.

Answer (score 13):

```
$('#foo').fadeOut("slow", function(){
  $('#foo').html(data);
  $('#foo').fadeIn("slow");
}
```

Comment: Sorry I should have been more explicit, the new `<div id="foo"></div>` is actually different - it's loaded with ajax so what I really want is `$('#foo').replaceWith(data.foo)` - but with fades.

Comment: You can simply replace the html within the div with html() before fading in.  I've revised my answer above.

Answer (score 4):

I successfully use this pattern to GET+fadeOut+fadeIn (with jQuery 1.11.0):

```
$.get(url).done(function(data) {
    $target.fadeOut(function() {
        $target.replaceWith(function() {
            return $(data).hide().fadeIn();
        });
    });
});
```

where `$target` is the element to replace.

Answer (score 2):

Richard Daltons answer is correct and is useful.

In case anyone else is looking to solve a very similar situation, but with a lot more content being updated, the following worked for me. My example includes 'response', which is an Ajax returned heap of HTML.

```
$('.foo').fadeOut("slow", function() {
  var div = jQuery('<div style="display:none;" class="foo">'+response+'</div>');
  $('.foo').replaceWith(div);
  $('.foo').fadeIn("slow");
});
```

The reason with the .hide() needs to be changed is that it applies it to all elements within the response. There may be more elegant solutions than this, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

This version will 'live' on ;)

[jsfiddle effort](http://jsfiddle.net/PHPsycho/szZ3v/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use shuffle function written by James Padolsey with a little modification:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.shuffle = function() {
        var allElems = this.get(),
            getRandom = function(max) {
                return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
            },
            shuffled = $.map(allElems, function(){
                var random = getRandom(allElems.length),
                    randEl = $(allElems[random]).clone(true)[0];
                allElems.splice(random, 1);
                return randEl;
            });

        this.each(function(i){

            $(this).fadeOut(700, function(){
                $(this).replaceWith($(shuffled[i]));
                $(shuffled[i]).fadeIn(700);
            });

        });
        return $(shuffled);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

And then in your handler use $('.albums .album').shuffle(); to shaffle your elements with fade.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a jQuery plugin to handle this.

It allows for a callback function which can be passed the replacement element.

```
$('#old').replaceWithFade(replacementElementSelectorHtmlEtc,function(replacement){
   replacement.animate({ "left": "+=50px" }, "slow" );
});
```

The plugin

```
(function($){
   $.fn.replaceWithFade = function(el, callback){
        numArgs = arguments.length;
        this.each(function(){
            var replacement = $(el).hide();
            $(this).fadeOut(function(){
                $(this).replaceWith(replacement);
                replacement.fadeIn(function(){
                    if(numArgs == 2){
                        callback.call(this, replacement);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

lesser code, this works for me:

```
  $jq('#taggin').replaceWith($jq('#rotator'));
  $jq('#rotator').fadeIn("slow").show();
```

replace "slow" with ms (eg 2000)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.
Example. Replace p element with `'<p>content</p>'`. Keep hide() and fadeIn() attached to element to replace and within replaceWith argument.

```
$('p').replaceWith($('<p>content</p>').hide().fadeIn('slow'));
```