# Why the difference when using percentage vs px to define height?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve the fade-in and fade-out effect as mentioned here [Jquery replacewith fade/animate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248721/jquery-replacewith-fade-animate), but I would like to avoid content below it moving up and down. So I define a container with fixed height.

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="foo"></div>
</div>
<h1>content below</h1>
```

If I set the height of container using px, "content below" will not move up and down during the animation.

```
.container {
  height: 475px;
}
```

But if I set "height: 90%;", then it will. Why?

I prefer to use percentage, so how to in this case?

Comment: Percentage works when you have a parent container of fixed height or of content. In your case the content is none so % of nothing is turning out to be nothing. But fixed height serves the purpose as that is absolute height in px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percentages are relative and pixels are absolute. The computer knows what 400 pixels is. However when the measurement is relative, the final absolute output must have a relation with some other measurement. 400px is 50% of 800px.

If example you have no content in your `<body>`, the page collapses and it has no height.

If you set `<body>`'s height to 100%, it still has no height because its parent `<html>` has no height. However by setting `<html>`'s and `<body>`'s heights to 100% you will fill the viewport (html's "parent").

This applies to other block elements like divs.

Comment: I forget to mention that I do have "html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; }". I will put everything together and test more. Another thing, I also use Bootstrap, so it may complicate. I don't know. I will try. Thank you.

Comment: I found that when using bootstrap, should use "vh" as %.

Answer (score 0):

Pixels are an absolute unit of measure. Percents are relative to some other value.

Each have valid use cases, neither is "better".

Reference : [More detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226439/what-is-the-difference-between-pixels-and-percentage-in-css)

Comment: I mean: given my question and when the window size doesn't change is "height: 90%" a fixed value or not? I am not asking the difference in general sense.

Comment: @user180574 `CSS: why the difference when using percentage vs px to define height?`

Comment: its not fixed value its change with your screen