# How to play one css anmation before chaging innerHTML and another one after it?

Tags: javascript, css-animations

What I need is this: when I click the button I want the old text to slowly disappear, then I want the new one to slowly appear.

But the disappear animation never gets played. Here's my code:

css

```
.quote-container {
    opacity: 0;
}

.appear {
    opacity: 0;
    animation: fadeIn 1200ms ease-in forwards;
}

.disappear {
    opacity: 1;
    animation: fadeOut 1200ms ease-in;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

javascript

```
let pickARandomQuote = () => {
    index = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
    currentQuote = quotes[index].quote;
    currentAuthor = quotes[index].author;

    console.log(currentQuote + " \n" + currentAuthor);

    let quoteContainer = document.getElementById("quote-container");

    quoteContainer.classList.add("disappear");
    void quoteContainer.offsetWidth;
    quoteContainer.classList.remove("disappear");
    void quoteContainer.offsetWidth;
    quoteContainer.classList.remove("appear");
    
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = currentQuote;
    document.getElementById("author").innerHTML = "- " + currentAuthor;

    void quoteContainer.offsetWidth;
    quoteContainer.classList.add("appear");

    return {
        quote: currentQuote,
        author: currentAuthor
    };
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", pickARandomQuote);

let button = document.getElementById("new-quote");

if (button) {
    button.addEventListener("click", pickARandomQuote);
}
```

It seems like the animation on the screen happens independently from the code, so "disappear" animation doesn't have enough time to get played. I tried "setTimeout", but it didn't help though.

Comment: Can you show me your sample HTML?

Comment: @pond27, yeah

<div class="quote-box" id="quote-box">

        <div class="quote-container" id="quote-container">
            <div class="text" id="text">
                
            </div>

            <div class="author" id="author">
                
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="buttons">
            <button class="btn" id="new-quote">New quote</button>
            <button class="btn">
                <a href="twitter.com/intent/tweet" id="tweet-quote" target="_blank">Tweet quote</a>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait till `disappear` animation ends before executing `appear`.
One of the approaches is `setTimeout` function.

Example:

```
let pickARandomQuote = function() {
    index = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
    currentQuote = quotes[index].quote;
    currentAuthor = quotes[index].author;
    let quoteContainer = document.getElementById("quote-container");

    quoteContainer.classList.remove("appear");
    quoteContainer.classList.add("disappear");
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = currentQuote;
        document.getElementById("author").innerHTML = "- " + currentAuthor;
        quoteContainer.classList.remove("disappear");
        quoteContainer.classList.add("appear");
    }, this.duration)
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", { handleEvent: pickARandomQuote, duration: 0 });

let button = document.getElementById("new-quote");

if (button) {
    button.addEventListener("click", { handleEvent: pickARandomQuote, duration: 1200 });
}
```

However, if you can use `jQuery`, the following Q&A may work for you.

[Jquery replacewith fade/animate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248721/jquery-replacewith-fade-animate)